# Windows installation through http URL

Tags: http, automation, command-line-interface, windows-server-2012

We have created a http URL and stored the windows setup files. Our requirements is to execute this setup files through HTTP.

we tried with command CURL http://192.168.2.20/win2k12/setup.exe but it shows only the ASCII characters.

Also is it possible to execute the .exe files through wget?

Can anyone help us how to execute the setup.exe file from command prompt?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here. What OS are you running the CURL command from?  You can do `curl http://192.168.2.20/win2k12/setup.exe > setup.exe` to create the file, but then setup.exe is a windows executable, and it'll look for all of the data files in the setup folder.  I'd suggest you search "PXE install Windows" - it isn't http, but it's ... more standard.

Comment: Acutally we are trying to install windows 2012 R2 through network. windows was booted in winpe environment and it shows the windows command prompt as x:\windows\system32. from this point, how to access the setup file which is stored in the http (http://192.168.2.20/win2k12/setup.exe). Is it possible to do that? or else should we need to use some other way.